# How do I identify a problem flagged by JET.JL?

Tags: dataframe, julia, diagnostic-tools

I started using JET.jl recently. In most cases it is helpful. However, sometimes I just cannot figure out why it has a problem with my code. An example is below. The function `foo` is very basic and works fine. Still, JET.jl’s macro `@report_call` reports an error. I cannot figure out what it is. What is the best way to identify the problem using the information provided by the macro call?

```
using DataFrames, JET
df = DataFrame(:A => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
# 4×1 DataFrame
# Row │ A       
#     │ Float64
# ─────┼─────────
#  1 │     1.0
#  2 │     2.0
#  3 │     3.0
#  4 │     4.0

function foo(df::DataFrame)::DataFrame
    v = 1:nrow(df)
    df[!, :B] = v

    return df
end
# foo (generic function with 1 method)

foo(df)
# 4×2 DataFrame
# Row │ A        B     
#     │ Float64  Int64
# ─────┼────────────────
#   1 │     1.0      1
#   2 │     2.0      2
#   3 │     3.0      3
#   4 │     4.0      4

julia> @report_call foo(df)
═════ 1 possible error found ═════
┌ @ REPL[20]:3 df[:, :B] = v
│┌ @ C:\Users\fsald\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:721 df[DataFrames.:!, col_ind] = DataFrames.copy(v)
││┌ @ C:\Users\fsald\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:669 DataFrames.insert_single_column!(df, v, col_ind)
│││┌ @ C:\Users\fsald\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:653 DataFrames._drop_all_nonnote_metadata!(df)
││││┌ @ C:\Users\fsald\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\other\metadata.jl:759 DataFrames._drop_table_nonnote_metadata!(df)
│││││┌ @ C:\Users\fsald\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\other\metadata.jl:752  = iterate(metadatakeys(df), getfield(_3, 2))
││││││┌ @ tuple.jl:68 t[i]
│││││││┌ @ tuple.jl:29 Base.getfield(t, i, $(Expr(:boundscheck)))
││││││││ invalid builtin function call
```

Comment: It does not happen here.  Could you have another version of foo defined as well?

Comment: @Bill - This code was run in a brand new environment created with `activate --temp` to which only the packages JET and DataFrames were added. Just to make sure there were no other objects around, after I saw your comment I recreated that environment from scratch, copied and pasted the code in the question and got the same "possible error" message that is in the question above. The error message is not due to the presence of any other objects. I am running Julia v1.8.1 on Windows 11 with DataFrames v1.4.1 and JET v0.6.9 and no other packages in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to JET.jl not handling correctly type unstable code with small type union. Here is an example:

```
julia> function f()
           x = rand(Bool) ? () : (1,)
           for v in x
               println(v)
           end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @report_call f()
═════ 1 possible error found ═════
┌ @ REPL[26]:5  = iterate(x, getfield(_2, 2))
│┌ @ tuple.jl:68 t[i]
││┌ @ tuple.jl:29 Base.getfield(t, i, $(Expr(:boundscheck)))
│││ invalid builtin function call: Base.getfield(t::Tuple{}, i::Int64, $(Expr(:boundscheck)))
││└───────────────
```

I reported it at https://github.com/aviatesk/JET.jl/issues/404

Answer (score 0):

I had no error using DataFrames v1.3.6, but with updating DataFrames to your version DataFrames v1.4.1 I got this error:

```
julia> @report_call foo(df)
═════ 1 possible error found ═════
┌ @ REPL[9]:3 Base.materialize!(Base.dotview(df, !, :B), Base.broadcasted(identity, v))
│┌ @ broadcast.jl:868 Base.Broadcast.materialize!(Base.Broadcast.combine_styles(dest, bc), dest, bc)
││┌ @ broadcast.jl:871 Base.Broadcast.copyto!(dest, Base.Broadcast.instantiate(Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{1}}(bc.f, bc.args, Base.Broadcast.axes(dest))))
│││┌ @ C:\Users\wherr\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\other\broadcasting.jl:210 df[DataFrames.:!, lazydf.col] = col
││││┌ @ C:\Users\wherr\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:669 DataFrames.insert_single_column!(df, v, col_ind)
│││││┌ @ C:\Users\wherr\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:653 DataFrames._drop_all_nonnote_metadata!(df)
││││││┌ @ C:\Users\wherr\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\other\metadata.jl:759 DataFrames._drop_table_nonnote_metadata!(df)
│││││││┌ @ C:\Users\wherr\.julia\packages\DataFrames\Lrd7K\src\other\metadata.jl:752  = iterate(metadatakeys(df), getfield(_3, 2))
││││││││┌ @ tuple.jl:68 t[i]
│││││││││┌ @ tuple.jl:29 Base.getfield(t, i, $(Expr(:boundscheck)))
││││││││││ invalid builtin function call
│││││││││└───────────────
```

I think you may want to report a bug in DataFrames 1.4.1, perhaps in src\other\broadcasting.jl, that may not be in v1.3.6. Your code reported a possible bug in a different line of code, so it may not be at either of the locations reported.

Comment: I reported a bug in DataFrames 1.4.1 and the answer was that the bug is in JET.jl.